# Как принять данные в одном потоке через один сокет, а отослать их через другой сокет, находящийся в другом потоке?

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket

Есть несколько потоков. Каждый из них может принимать данные.
При приеме данных с клиента необходимо отослать эти данные другим клиентам.
Для этого в пространстве, где хранятся потоки, обрабатывающие команды пользователей и хранящие в себе их данные и сокет, я создал массив, хранящий дескрипторы всех активных сокетов.
Каждый поток так же имеет в себе ссылку на этот массив.
При приходе данных вызывается метод, который создает новые сокеты по этим дескрипторам, а затем отсылает данные. Сделал я это потому, что в Qt каждый поток работает со своими сокетами, созданными в нем. Т.е. нельзя просто передать по указателю сокет в другой поток.
Но в строке, где я устанавливаю дескриптор, вылетает ошибка: QSocketNotifier: Multiple socket notifiers for same socket 972 and type Read, и программа падает...
Я не знаю, что не так. Ломаю голову уже 4 дня без успехов.
Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: то есть, Вы создаете Qt сокет вокруг дескриптора каждый раз, когда Вам нужно с этим сокетом поработать?

Comment: @KoVadim эх, да... Я настолько новичок в этом, что даже стыдно...
От Вас это прозвучало, будто это полный бред...

Comment: ну это как минимум сильно-сильно странное решение. Даже если Qt сокеты находятся в разных потоках - Вы все равно можете через сигнал-слот послать сообщение. Главное пятый параметр connect сделайте QueuedConnection и гарантируйте, что бы буфер будет валидный. Другой поток будет обрабатывать свою очередь событий, дойдет до этого и обработает. Но в целом, в Qt можно обрабатывать много-много подключений в одном потоке и Вашей проблемы не получить. Много - 10к-20к сокетов.

Comment: в одном потоке оно почти всегда пишется легко и непринужденно. Особенно, если вся архитектура подразумевает асинхронность (прилетел запрос - обработали - послали ответ)

Comment: @Sazoks главный поток для интерфейса, второй поток для сети. каждое соединение оберните в qobject со слотом "сообщение полученно", этот слот подпишите на общий сигнал. ИЛИ положите все сокеты в один объект со слотом в котором в цикле всем отправите

Comment: всё конечно делать надо через readyRead

Comment: Приведите код, который даёт такую ошибку. И укажите метку языка